# extract images from HL7 files

Tags: image, hl7

Given a HL7 file which I know that in its TXA segment there's a byte code of an image, how can I extract that image?

I know my question might be blurry, but that's the details I have

EDIT: The TXA segment is as follows:

> TXA|1|25^PathologyResultsReport|8^HTML|||||||||||||||||||908^מעבדת^פתולוגיה^^^^^^^^^^^^20110710084900|||PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWwgUFVCTElDICItLy9XM0MvL0RURCBYSFRNTCAxLjAgU3RyaWN0Ly9FTiIgImh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnL1RSL3hodG1sMS9EVEQveGh0bWwxLXN0cmljdC5kdGQiPg0KPGh0bWw+PGhlYWQ+PG1ld...
>   +PGJyLz48L3RkPjwvdHI+DQo8dHI+PHRkPg0KPC90ZD48L3RyPg0KPC90Ym9keT4NCjwvdGFibGU+DQo8L3RkPjxTb2ZUb3ZOZXdDb2x1bW4gLz48L3RyPjxTb2ZUb3ZOZXdMaW5lIC8+DQo8L3Rib2R5Pg0KPC90YWJsZT4NCjwvYm9keT4NCjwvaHRtbD4NCg==|

Thanks in advance

Comment: Opensource solution for viewing HL7 files can be your help here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/quickviewhl7/

Comment: @nrathaus I've found this program in a web search before asking this here, I couldn't find a way to extract the image. I've also copied the entire TXA segment to another file and tried to convert it to TIFF or JPG and it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reading the documentation it appears that images are stored in this form:

```
OBX||TX|11490-0^^LN||^IM^TIFF^Base64^
SUkqANQAAABXQU5HIFRJRkYgAQC8AAAAVGl0bGU6AEF1dGhvcjoAU3ViamVjdDoAS2V5d29yZHM6~
AENvbW1lbnRzOgAAAFQAaQB0AGwAZQA6AAAAAABBAHUAdABoAG8AcgA6AAAAAABTAHUAYgBqAGUA~
YwB0ADoAAAAAAEsAZQB5AHcAbwByAGQAcwA6AAAAAABDAG8AbQBtAGUAbgB0AHMAOgAAAAAAAAAA~
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASAP4ABAABAAAAAAAAAAAB~
                                   (681 lines omitted)
1qqQS/cFpaSVeD1QP1/SX1VJfpPSfXr+tIOKrN2aSrB8OHoH1kfz2tnPLpB/6WkksJ0w5G6WKVNe~
vSisJQdhLdQjODpbznVXXDMPdBNhVtBNpOqqtkY60qYoJxQK17cUoS0v4ijYztCapqqYUKmIUJhJ~
sKqoIO2opiqr7lupIMFBBhNQmtOIzG4naS7XsQuDBLFOP/gAgAgAAKMHAACcBgAACRcAALcYAAC4~
EwAA5RoAALQXAADyBAAAnAMAAD8LAADbEQAA5CgAAJtBAABTVQAAOHAAAOyHAAA=|||||||F
```

This looks like a simple structure, where the image data is base64 encoded and stored as a long stream, you know its an image because it has `^IM` and the image type because of `^TIFF`

More specifically:
When an image is sent, OBX-2 must contain the value ED which stands for encapsulated data. The components of OBX-5 must be as described below.

1. The first component, source application, must be null.
2. Component 2, type of data, must contain IM, indicating image data.
3. Component 3, data subtype, must contain TIFF
4. Component 4, encoding, must contain Base64

Comment: For some reason my superiors told me that I should expect the image in the TXA segment and not OBX. But you've done big effort to help me, thanks :) here's your upvote and accpetance.

Comment: Not sure why they mentioned TXA, OBX is used to store data, see http://medinfo.cdac.in/repo/docs/ref/HL7%20v2.0/JAVA/cdac/medinfo/sdk/hl725/baselibs/segments/OBX.html

Comment: I think TXA can also be used for images, as it is a data storage for documents, which can be images

Comment: OK, so how would I convert the bytes inside the TXA segment to image?

Comment: Do you have a TXA data sample? I can't find one, so I am not sure

Comment: From what I can see, you need to parse (like you do with OBX) the IM
segment

Comment: I've edited my question with the TXA segment. thanks

Comment: 1) yep :) Israel forever! 2) how would I extract html out of it? maybe it's an image inside html

Comment: I don't think HTML would have an embedded image in it, but who knows :} anyway, I am pretty sure it is base64 encoded data, do you know how to decode that? if so just take from ``|||P`` to ``|`` and decode it into a file

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to do that...may I ask you to guide me?

Comment: 1) Put in pastebin the ``block`` you copy/pasted, so that I can guide you through it, 2) What programming language are you using? 3) What OS are you running on?

Answer (score 0):

Base64 encoding of non-structured (standard HL7) data, normally in an OBX (but could be anywhere) is the norm. Older systems may have a 32K or 64K byte limit, and when that happens the data will be spread over multiple segments.

The target system will first have to potentially concatenate multiple segments and then decode the Base64 encoding.

The target system must know what the expected data type is so that it can be properly displayed or further decoded/interpreted.

This would be a great question on our new StackExchange site for IT Healthcare: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51758/healthcare-it